# Is it possible to catch None in except statement?

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch, except

I'm working on a program that represents a month in number.
Each month name and number are stored in a dictionary, with the key being the month name.

The program needs to take the month name as input and output its corresponding number.
In case the provided input is not a month, output **"Not found"**
It always returns `None` if input isn't a month.
How to do this?
My code:

```
mon ={"January":1,
      "February":2, 
      "March":3,
      "April":4,
      "May":5,
      "June":6,
      "July":7,
      "August":8,
      "September":9,
      "October":10,
      "November":11,
      "December":12
}
try:
    num = input()
    print(mon.get(num))
except KeyError:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` Can return a default value if there is no key.
The `None` you were getting was the default return value for `.get()`.

```py
def foo(x):

    mon = {"January": 1,
           "February": 2,
           "March": 3,
           "April": 4,
           "May": 5,
           "June": 6,
           "July": 7,
           "August": 8,
           "September": 9,
           "October": 10,
           "November": 11,
           "December": 12
           }

    return mon.get(x, "Not found")
```

```py
>>> print(foo("Test"))
'Not found'
>>> print(foo("July"))
7
```

---

Syntax: `.get("key","Default value")`

> [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get)

Comment: Thanks, it means we can't use try-except statements for this?

Comment: No worries, You can use them if you'd like, but it's better not to. You would use `print(mon[num])` rather than `print(mon.get(num))` which would cause a key error. Or you could assign `x = mon[num]` before printing, so you skip to the except block before printing `None`